# Speed up multiplication of matrix by transposed

Tags: matrix, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

Given a matrix `A` of size `(m, n)`, is there a way to speed up `A @ A.t()` in `PyTorch` since the resulting matrix is symmetric and about half of the computations are redundant?

Comment: Star operator `*` usually used for elementwise multiplication, while for matrix multiplication it is `@`. Considering you're transposing, do you mean matrix multiplication?

Comment: I don't see why you are mentioning the elementwise operator here, OP refers to the matrix multiplication `A@A.T` which results in a symmetric matrix.

Comment: I edited the question, before I wrongly used the `*` operator